# Why single backslash turns to double backslash

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, jsonkit

The string `"\domain\path1\path2"` was turned to `"\\domain\\path1\\path2"` after using AFNetwork to get the JSON response.

I got two comments "they are same",but the point is that when we use NSURL to create a remote url for EGOImageView to load, that will be different. The double `\\` will get failed.

Why this happened ?

Comment: Confirm, they are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash character is an escape character which is usually followed by a control character. The escape sequence for a literal backlash is `\\`. It's worth noting that the backslash is not a path separator in iOS. That would be a forward slash.